# Linq statement in C# with multiple filters with Any()

Tags: c#, linq

I have a snippet with LINQ statement that needs modification for the problem statement below.

```
var orders = ordersets.Where(OrderSetIsOk).ToList(); 
var orderOther = ordersets.Except(orders).ToList();

private bool OrderSetIsOk(OrderSet value)
{
    bool result = false;
    var privateorders = user.privateorders;

    result = privateorders.Any(a => a.strHead == value.Code ||
                                    (a.10Code == value.10Code) ||
                                    (value.Complaint != null &&
                                     a.strHead == value.Complaint.9Code));

    return result;
}
```

I have example ordersets like these:

```
A : value.10code = "B6"; value.Code = "" 
B : value.10code = "G6"; value.code = ""
c : value.10code = "G6"; value.code = "189"
```

Problem: When the a.strHead is "" and value.code = "189" and value.10code = "G6". B and C should return true but A should return false. I need to change the Any statement so A returns false but B and C returns true. Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but are you _sure_ you understand what `Any` does?

This snippet will return `true` if _any_ element of `user.privateorders` matches any single condition in your boolean statement.

Comment: You need to actually describe the criteria you're trying to implement. If you leave it up to us to work it out from the code then we can only conclude that the code works because it does exactly what it does.

Comment: A returns because the first condition passes for it: Value.Code = "" for A, and so is a.strHead, thus A will appear in your lists.

Comment: Sorry I modified the Problem statement for more clarity. I need to change the Any statement so A returns false but is true for B and C.

Comment: One should use the power of differed execution until the data is actually needed. Remove the `ToList()` from the orders and orderOther. The call to the `Any` will provide a value and get the data as needed.

Comment: The call to Any is my problem right? The call to the Any returns true for "A". I need add something to make it false but also satisfy B and C

Comment: Don't you just need `All` instead of `Any`?

Answer (score 0):

Its best to normalize the data before the code gets to the `Any`. I suggest you remove most empty values and keep only the specific "G6" need such as

```
 privateorders.Where(ord => !string.IsNullOrEmtpy(ord.Code) || ord.10code = "G6")
              .Any( …_)
```

Hence they have been removed from consideration. Work out the `Where` logic as needed.

Comment: But then it will remove B from consideration. I cant hardcode the || ord.10Code = "G6", there are 1000s of records this code will run for sets like these. That's the sticky thing here. So the ones with both Strhead = " " and value.code = " " should be included unless the 10code don't match.

Comment: The data considerations have to be accounted for....again work out the `Where` logic as needed...I can't answer to your business logic needs, I can only show a tool to help in the process. :-)

Comment: Also this is filtering PrivateOrders, I need all the privateorders but match the right OrderSet to the privateorders.

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
results = privateorders.Where(a => a.strHead == value.Code ||
                                    (a.10Code == value.10Code) ||
                                    (value.Complaint != null &&
                                     a.strHead == value.Complaint.9Code)).ToList();
```